# I have a problem parsing SubMsgResponse data (binary) to specific type

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

I have a factory contract that can instantiate offspring contract. In factory contract there is **create_offspring** that return **CosmWasm::Instantiate** and I added a **reply** function to handle the response. Here is the **reply** function in **factory/contract.rs** that will parse the Reply SubMsgResult response:

```rust
let owner: Option<String> = match msg.clone().result {
            SubMsgResult::Ok(s) => match s.data {
                Some(bin) => {
                    match from_binary::<OffspringInfo>(&bin) {
                        Ok(d) => {                            
Some(d.owner.to_string())
                        }
```

Here is code from **offspring/contract.rs** that instantiates and return the data binary:

```rust
let user_address: OffspringInfo = OffspringInfo{
        owner: msg.user
};


Ok(Response::new().set_data(to_binary(&user_address)?))
```

I got the following error:

`Error parsing into type factory::structs::OffspringInfo: Invalid type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw data returned from the instantiate function is an encoded protobuf and therefore you would need to utilize the "**parse_reply_instantiate_data**" function from cw_utils to parse the data (https://docs.rs/cw-utils/latest/cw_utils/fn.parse_reply_instantiate_data.html).